# Output IDs from playGetIDs to a Vector in R

Tags: r, indexing, output, interactive

Here's a set of x and y pairs:

```
x = c( 3, 1,  2, 10,  9,  8,  6,  7,  5,  4)
y = c(15, 5, 10, 50, 45, 40, 30, 35, 25, 20)
```

I would like to be able to interactively identify the indices of this data, and store the indices of the identified points in the order they were identified.

Even though `identify()` says that it will do this with `pos = FALSE`, I couldn't get that to work.

I would prefer to use playwith if possible - it is really easy to zoom in to areas with high densities of points, select the points, zoom out, and then keep selecting points.

Here's a good start, borrowed from "copeg":

```
 playwith(xyplot(y ~ x, main = "Select Points to Delete, then close"),
    width = 4, height = 3.5, show.toolbars = FALSE,
    on.close = confirmClose, modal = FALSE,
    click.mode = "Brush")
```

After the plot loads, select points, then

```
 index <- playGetIDs()
```

I've tried all kinds of alternatives to the `playGetIDs()` line, but I can't get it to populate `index` with the IDs in the order they were selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a non-modal window, the playwith function will return immediately, returning a playState object.

```
ps = playwith(xyplot(y ~ x, main = "Select Points to Delete, then close"),
    width = 4, height = 3.5, show.toolbars = FALSE,
    click.mode = "Brush")
```

You can then select the points in the plot, and when finished get the IDs from the playState object.

```
selectedIDs = playGetIDs(ps);
```

Alternative, the zoom package has a zm() function to zoom a plot, and can be used together with identify, although the calls must be independent:

```
library(zoom)
plot(x,y)
zm()
#use mouse or keys to navigate and zoom, then exit
chosen = identify(x,y) 
zm()
#zoom to another location if needed
chosen = c(chosen, identify(x,y))
#etc...
```

Note that I've found the functionality of this package dependent upon R version (I have 2.1, 2.14, and 3.2 and it only works with 3.2)

Comment: I'm pretty interested in the playwith package - the GUI is so friendly.  But your suggestion is a great alternative if I can't figure playwith out - your code was almost functional in 3.1.2, but not really.  I'll try updating.

Comment: See edit. If you don't need modality, you can use a non-modal dialog and gather plot information from the playState object

Comment: Nice; that particular code didn't work for me, but I was able to populate a vector with `ind <- playGetIDs()`.  Unforunately, `playGetIDs()` isn't populating `ind` in the order I click on the data... sounds like a silly preference, but it would really improve my script.  Thanks!

Comment: Wait, your code works for me, too.  It wasn't working when I ran the two lines as a chunk, but it works fine if I run the plot, then run playGetIDs().  Still not sure how to get the ordering issue resolved.  The default appears to be ordered from least to greatest indice.